# Инициализация полей по аннотациям

Tags: java, аннотации, property

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть класс нужно заполнить его поля из файла property.properties, используя аннотации?

Comment: Правил извиняюсь

Answer (score 2):

Если без спринга

```
public class ValueTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ValueTest valueTest = new ValueTest();
        valueTest.getPropValues();
    }

    public  void getPropValues() throws IOException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "hello.properties";

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        prop.load(inputStream);
        String message = prop.getProperty("message");

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

> hello.properties
 message = hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Если ручками делать то получится приблизительно следующее

Файл prop.properties в `/src`

```
name = John
age = 15
pass = 12345
```

Файл Man(Класс для заполнения)

```
@InitClass
public class Man {
    @InitField
    String name;
    @InitField
    Integer age;
    @InitField
    String pass;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Man{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", pass='" + pass + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Файл с аннотацией для класса

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface InitClass {
}
```

Файл с аннотацией для полей

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InitField {
}
```

Класс для проверки аннотация и инициализации полей из файла(берет имя поля и ищет такой же ключ в properties). Чтобы приводить данный из properties к типу полей нашел в пакете sun `TypeConverter`. Сразу думал сам писать(но это очень не приятно). Также тут нету проверок и обработок исключительных ситуаций. Думаю добавите)

Но лучше наверное Spring

```
import sun.plugin.com.TypeConverter;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Initialization {

    public void initializationValues(Object object, Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
        if (object != null) {
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(InitClass.class)) {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("prop.properties");
                properties.load(is);
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(InitField.class)) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(object, castObject(field.getType(), properties.getProperty(field.getName())));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private <T> T castObject(Class<T> to, Object from) {
        return (T) TypeConverter.convertObject(to, from);
    }

}
```

И собственно класс Main для проверки работы

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Man man = new Man();
        new Initialization().initializationValues(man, Man.class);
        System.out.println(man);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Spring framework или Spring Boot, то можете воспользоваться аннотацией @Value
Например, имеется класс

```
public class SomeTestClass {
    private String host;
    private int port;
}
```

И имеется конфигурационный файл application.properties

```
application.port=8080
application.host=localhost
```

То для того, чтобы spring заполнил информацию класса настройками из файла, класс необходимо сделать spring-бином (например, с помощью аннотации Configuration) и добавить над каждым полем название конфигурации в файле:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeTestClass {
    @Value("{application.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("{application.port}")
    private int port;
}
```

Надеюсь это то, что требовалось.

Comment: Если нужно делать то же самое, но самостоятельно, то вот примерный план действий: 1. Написать класс аннотации (public @interface ConfigValue) 2. Создать некий ObjectAdapter, в котором получать доступ к аннотированным полям класса и, одновременно, хранить адрес ресурса с конфигурацией 3. При обнаружении поля, аннотированного целевой аннотацией парсить и инжектить из файла настройку в искомый объект

Comment: А если реализовать свою аннотацию например @Example(propertyName = "com.mycompany.name") 
private String myCompanyName;

Comment: Конкретная реализация может быть любой, на ваше усмотрение. Алгоритм создания же обязательно должен в себя включать еще и обработчик этой аннотации

Comment: Есть возможность связаться вне форума? В личке пару вопросов задать?